# Legacy Spring MVC to Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

I have a legacy application which uses web.xml configuration.
The web.xml looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring/common-beans-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherOne</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherOne-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherOne</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherTwo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherTwo-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherTwo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

To Convert this to Spring Boot Application,

I have done the below changes:

```
@Bean
    public XmlWebApplicationContext xmlWebApplicationContext() {
        XmlWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setConfigLocations("classpath:spring/common-beans-context.xml");
        applicationContext.refresh();
        return applicationContext;
    }

@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> mvcTestServlet(XmlWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        // create child application context
        XmlWebApplicationContext childApplicationContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        childApplicationContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:spring/dispatcherOne-context.xml");
        // set parent from the previous method
        childApplicationContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(childApplicationContext);
        childApplicationContext.refresh();
        ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet>(
                dispatcherServlet, "/test/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("dispatcherOne");
        servletRegistrationBean.addUrlMappings("/test/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> mvcServlet(XmlWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        // similar to the previous method..
        // 1. create local applicationContext and then set parent.
    }
```

I added childApplicationContext.refresh() to see if the beans were loading properly but what i think is happening is that the two dispatcher servlets are not able to access the beans defined in the parentContext. and are throwing beans not found exception even though they're available in parentContext

Is there a workaround for this?

or is there any other way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

To create a Spring Boot application and re-using your existing config do the following and don't create a context yourself. You are basically trying to outsmart or work-around Spring Boot with what you are currently doing.

Create a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and use `@ImportResource` to let Spring Boot creat the main application context.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/common-beans-context.xml")
public YourApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
  }

  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(YourApplication.class);
  } 
}
```

Now as you have 2 `DispatcherServlet`s in your original config you need to add  2 `ServletRegistrationBean` to set the URL etc.

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> dispatcherServletOneRegistration() {
  ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet(), "/test/*");
  registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  registration.setName("dispatcherOne");
  registration.setInitParameters(Collections.singletonMap("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring/dispatcherOne-context.xml");
  return registration;
}
```

And more or less the same for the second servlet.

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> dispatcherServletTwoRegistration() {
  ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet(), "/");
  registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  registration.setName("dispatcherTwo");
  registration.setInitParameters(Collections.singletonMap("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:spring/dispatcherTwo-context.xml");
  return registration;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I understand what you're trying to do here and I did the same change but what I am seeing is that/WEB-INF/dispatcherOne-context.xml is not having any effect on application startup. The beans defined in that file are not being loaded. I actually tried to give a wrong name for that file(WEB-INF/dispatcherOneTEST-context.xml), still the code is not flagging that as an issue. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Why would that code need to be flagged? If that isn't loading you aren't starting the Spring Boot app properly. As mentioned you need the `YourApplication` class and put those 2 `@Bean` methods in there. If that doesn't work you are still working against Spring Boot instead of utilizing the framework, but there is too little information in your post to definitely say that.

Comment: I have done the exact same thing but it just wont load the beans defined in the file "classpath:spring/dispatcherOne-context.xml" although the code executes the method dispatcherServletOneRegistration without any issues. 
does it have anything to do with the name of the method/file ?

Comment: I also noticed one thing, the method 

`
@Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
  System.out.println("test"); // to see if it was called!
  return builder.sources(YourApplication.class);
 }
` never gets called.

Comment: That will only be called when you deploy the application as a war file to your tomcat servlet (which I assumed you are going to do due to the old application) it won't get called if you run the main method. If the file cannot be loaded it will through an exception that it cannot find the file. If that doesn't happen something is preventing the regular servlet `init` method from being called.